# SQL First Normal Form (1NF) vs Serialisation

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-normalization

Lets say I have a football team table, where player names are tied to positions:

```
teamId: 1
goalkeeper: 'Marc'
position1: 'John'
position2: 'Erik'
...
```

But now I also want one attribute that represents the players NOT taking into account positions. I would create a new attribute `teamString` serialising all players sorted alphabetically (this will ensure that different `Teams` with same players will have the same `teamString` attribute):

```
teamString: Eric-John-Mark[...]
```

Now I can filter `Teams` with same players even if they play in different positions.

Will this new attribute `teamString` be against 1NF principle?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: you want to be able to get a list of players per team regardless of their position ?

Comment: Exactly, sometimes same player might be placed in a different position. Sometimes I will need to find teams by players regardless of their position.

Comment: Don't _store_ `Eric-John-Mark`, instead _compute_ it using `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) (All involve replacing some table with parameterized structure by some table(s) with a column per parameter.) So do "unnormalized" & "UNF" & "0NF" & for that matter "relation". So you need to tell us your definitions & preferably also textbook name & edition. And how is it you are stuck telling whether you have violated your chosen "1NF"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `teamString` attribute would be a violation of the **1NF** as your `teamString` property would contain multiple values. And it would reference values existing in non-key attributes of the same entity (maybe a **3NF** violation but I'm not sure about it).

The issue here is that you treated specific positions in a team as attributes of the team and not as a relation.

I'd make a relation between **team** and **player**:

```
team (1, n) - (0, n) player
```

> A **team** may have one to many players.
> A **player** may play for zero to many teams.

As both max cardinalities are to `n` you'd get a **Many To Many** relation which implies a **join table** with foreign keys from both sides (the team id + player id). In this table you can add a column for the position type.

> This means you should get rid of the position columns (`goalkeeper`, `position1`, ...) in the team table.

The **position** table could look like:

| team_id | player_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | goal_keeper |
| 1 | 15 | position1 |
| 2 | 12 | position_2 |

Then the application could be responsible for checking that a team has only a limited number of players for a specific position. But for modeling you should stick to the 0, 1 & "n" values that you use in cardinalities.